# как настроить кодировку для обратной формы php

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Настроил обратную форму php mailer . Залогинился в отлук форма работает но сообщения приходят так "Ð˜Ð¼Ñ: Ð¸Ð¼Ñ‚Ð¸Ð¼Ñ" вот форма.

```
<?php
// Файлы phpmailer
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Настройки
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = ''; // хост отправки
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                      
$mail->Username = ''; // Ваш логин в Яндексе. Именно логин, без @yandex.ru
$mail->Password = ''; // Ваш пароль
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->setFrom(''); // Ваш email
$mail->addAddress(''); // email получателя

// Прикрепление файлов
  for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        } else {
            $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }
    }   

// Письмо
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = "Feedback to Wing Chun"; // Заголовок письма
$mail->Body    = "Имя: $name . Сообщение: $message . Номер: $email"; // Текст письма

// Результат
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'ok';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите кодировку:

```
$mail->charSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Comment: если я правльно понял то надо устанавливать кодировку нужно в настройки мейлера. ну я так установил но в аутлуке все равно не отбображает кириллицу

Comment: а всё, в орфографии дело. $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; так надо было. спасибо.